# Product details from barcode

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, barcode, firebase-mlkit

I am using [Firebase Barcode Scanner](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes) and I need to get product information when the user scans it, for example, drink size (1l, 2l...), clothing size (m, l, xl), clothing color or something like that.

Is there a way to extract data from the barcode raw value?

```
workflowModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WorkflowModel::class.java)
workflowModel?.detectedBarcode?.observe(this, Observer { barcode ->
            if (barcode != null) {
                val barcodeFieldList = ArrayList<BarcodeField>()
                barcodeFieldList.add(BarcodeField("Raw Value", barcode.rawValue ?: ""))
                BarcodeResultFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, barcodeFieldList)

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

A barcode is just encoded numbers used as a reference, it only contains unique (sometimes not very unique) identifiers. It does not contain specific data outside of that.

A very basic example of how this works is: scan a barcode and get number 12345. Call to backend api or web service with reference number 12345. API or web service looks up product with unique key 12345 and returns metadata about the product back to your device.

I realize that this is out of scope of your question but if you are looking at ways to tag items with data directly attached then you would want to look at going towards RFID technology which can store data on-board (although still very limited.) If you are looking for direct interaction between mobile devices and this technology then you would want to head towards NFC (which is at a high level a subset of RFID.) The reason being is that some mobile devices have the ability to interact with NFC technology while they do not have the ability to interact with other forms of RFID without expensive add on peripherals (think employee badge readers.)

Hope this points you in the right direction. I’ve been through implementations such as this and I know how frustrating it can be as there are very limited published resources for dev on this topic.